# NuSoap vs PHP Soap Library. Where is getError?

Tags: php, soap, nusoap, soap-client

I'm converting an old code which use NuSoap to PHP Soap Library. But method getError in NuSoap PHP seems not exist in PHP Soap Libary and I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: 
[Client] Function ("getError") is not a valid method for this service in index.php:33
Stack trace: #0 index.php(33): SoapClient->__call('getError', Array) #1 index.php(33):
SoapClient->getError() #2 index.php(63): pay() #3 {main} thrown in /homeindex.php on line 33
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $client = new SoapClient('my soap server');
    $err = $client->getError();
?>
```

How I supposed to get error in PHP Soap library?

Comment: I had this problem to and when I changed SoapClient() to nusoap_client(), It solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
    $client = new SoapClient('my soap server');
    $err = $client->soapCall($somfunctioname,$arrofargs );

?>
```

If there is any error It with the soapCall .It returns a instance of SoapFault() where you can log the errorcode, description so.. on

http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php

Comment: Did you mean `$err = $client->__soapCall($somfunc,...`?